# Adding a row subtotal for certain columns only

Tags: tableau-api

I have data as shown in this table:
[image]

If I add a grand total column Io get sales and units across the window.

Is there a way to add a row total for only Contract Owners AAA and BBB? But not CCC & IDN?

Answer (score 1):

Arrange your data on the sheet as shown on the screenshot (using Measure Names and Measure Values), display subtotals and then use the individual measure pills to hide subtotals for selected measures.

[image]